# React Component inline style shorthand declaration overwriting each other

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a React component that gets passed a values object that looks like:

```
{gridColumn: '1 / 3', gridRow: '2 / 5', gridArea: 'header'}
```

to then add to a component's style like:

```
this.cell.style.setProperty('grid-area', values.gridArea);
this.cell.style.setProperty('grid-column', values.gridColumn);
this.cell.style.setProperty('grid-row', values.gridRow);
```

However, using grid-column and grid-row properties, these get abbreviated to a shorthand declaration of 'grid-area: 2 / 1 / 5 / 3' in the browser and overwrite my grid-area style.

This also happens if i set it in a loop:

```
for (let prop in values) {
  this.cell.style[prop] = values[prop];
};
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Did you try to calculate grid-area from gridColum and gridRow? It may solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From MDN:

- [grid-area](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area) is shorthand for `grid-row-start`, `grid-column-start`, `grid-row-end` and `grid-column-end`
- [grid-column](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column) is shorthand for `grid-column-start` and `grid-column-end`
- [grid-row](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row) is shorthand for `grid-row-start` and `grid-row-end`.

So `grid-area` is mutually exclusive with `grid-column` and `grid-row`. 
 React is not designed to intelligently merge these CSS properties for you, it is simply going to let the last one defined win.

You can, however, add the logic to merge these properties yourself:

```
  const mergedGridColumn = gridColumn.replace(/[0-9*]/g, value => `${value} ${gridArea}`);
  const mergedGridRow = gridRow.replace(/[0-9*]/g, value => `${value} ${gridArea}`);
```

For `values`:

```
{
  const values = {
  gridArea: 'header',
  gridColumn: '1 / 3',
  gridRow: '2 / 5',
}
```

This produces `style`:

```
{
  grid-area: 2 header / 1 header / 5 header / 3 header;
}
```

Full example below:

```js
const App = () => {
  const values = {
    gridArea: 'header',
    gridColumn: '1 / 3',
    gridRow: '2 / 5',
  };

  return (
    <div className="App" style={{display: 'grid'}}>
      <Header values={values} />
    </div>
  );
}

const Header = (props) => {
  const { gridArea, gridColumn, gridRow } = props.values;

  const mergedGridColumn = gridColumn.replace(/[0-9*]/g, value => `${value} ${gridArea}`);
  const mergedGridRow = gridRow.replace(/[0-9*]/g, value => `${value} ${gridArea}`);
  return (
    <div
      className="App-header"
      style={{
        gridColumn: mergedGridColumn,
        gridRow: mergedGridRow,
      }}
      >
      <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.App-header {
  background-color: orchid;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```